# tortoise hg creating 'sibling' branches

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

I'm just starting working with Mercurial and Tortoise HG. I've created two uncoupled changes, one is a bug fix and one is a new experimental feature.

What is the best way to set this up (using bookmarks, tags or branches or something else) so that I can commit both but push only one of the groups of changesets to the remote repository.

And can this be done easily in Tortoise HG or is command line knowledge of mercurial required?

Comment: I recommend adding the `mercurial` tag to questions like this in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from both the CLI and from TortoiseHg. Note that using bookmarks, tag, etc.. has no influence on what you can push.

**Using TortoiseHg v1.X.X**

Identify the outgoing changesets and then right-click on the head of the branch you'd like to push and select `push this branch`.

**Using TortoiseHg v2.X.X**

You must first configure the tool to allow pushing new named branches by clicking `Options` and selecting the following:

[image]

Using the Target option in the Synchronize view, select the branch you want to share and perform the push. This will only share the selected branch. Unchecking `Target` will cause every new changeset to be pushed.

[image]